# What is the quickest way to get a short-cut of a url on my desktop using Firefox on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, firefox

I have recently switched to Ubuntu from Windows where I was used to drag the icon on the left of the URL in the address bar of Firefox to my desktop to create a shortcut of the open page there. Now, in Ubuntu it doesn't create a link/shortcut, but rather it saves the content of the current page as a file.

Is there a way to get the Windows behavior?

Similar to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/102281/google-chrome-in-linuxmint-ubuntu-gnome-dragging-url-copies-page-not-url), but a different browser/OS setup. I'm on Ubuntu 10.04 and FF 3.6.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought the default behaviour is changed by the "ubuntu firefox modifications" add-on, because after disabling this add-on I could simply drag the url to my desktop to make a shortcut, like I was used to. 
However, after enabling it again I can still drag and drop URL shortcuts so my problem has resolved itself somehow.

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/65104/what-is-this-ubuntu-firefox-modifications-addon-in-ff-3-5-4-in-karmic/179883#179883) has useful information about the add-on and it seems like it doesn't do anything really useful, so I might leave it disabled.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely via the [deskCut](http://deskcut.mozdev.org/) add-on. It adds a shortcut option to your context menu in Firefox that will create a shortcut of the current page on your desktop:

[image]

Advertised to support Firefox 3.5 and under, but it is still working flawlessly in my Firefox 3.6.8, and according to others, Firefox 4.0 beta as well.

Comment: Install deskCut v0.6.0.1 (supports 3.0 - 3.6.*)

Comment: Yep, that was recently updated by the dev after others claimed it still worked in newer versions (see comments).

Comment: Thank you very much! Doing just what I have been looking for. Now I will just have to retrain my drag-and-drop habit to right-click and save.

Comment: While I was installing your suggested add-on (my first one under ubuntu), I discovered a better way of getting the behaviour I am used to. If I ever need to re-enable the ubuntu modifications add-on, I'll revert to your method. I sadly don't have enough reputation to vote you up.